# What about SEO if I load new posts every time user reaches the bottom?

Tags: php, seo

So, I am doing the same as Facebook, every time person reaches a bottom, he gets new posts via ajax. But what about SEO? It will be just one page and I am sure Google likes when site has lots of pages. What should I do?

Comment: Do you have to login to see the posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, Google-bot won't be scrolling to get more content, so you need to provide it some way of indexing it.

What you should probably do is use graceful degradation so that if JS is disabled, pagination is provided to access more posts.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be, assuming you're wanting to keep the ajax auto load, is using noscript, add a pagination option so that bots can traverse the pages.